# How to get response status 404 in casper.js within thenOpen instead of undefined?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Any idea why code below doesn't catch 404 in either `response` var or in the `http.status.404` event?

I run this with phantomjs 1.9, casperjs 1.0.2 and Windows 7

```
var casper = require("casper").create(),
    utils = require('utils');

casper.start();

casper.thenOpen('http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd', function(response) {
  casper.capture('test.png');
  utils.dump(response);
});

casper.on('http.status.404', function(resource) {
  this.echo('wait, this url is 404: ' + resource.url);
});

casper.run(function() {
  console.log('End');
  casper.exit();
});
```

Ideally I like to catch 404 within thenOpen(). How to do that?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried this

```
casper.thenOpen('http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd', function(response) {
  casper.capture('test.png');
  utils.dump(response);

    if(this.status(false)['currentHTTPStatus'] === 404) {
        console.log('Error 404');
    } else {
        console.log('No Error 404');
    }

});
```

And here is the output:

```
undefined
No Error 404
End
```

It still doesn't make sense.

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried 404checker.js here https://gist.github.com/n1k0/4509789

```
casperjs 404.js http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd
```

Output:

```
URI.js loaded
Starting
http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd
http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd is okay (HTTP 200)
1 new links found on http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd
All done, 1 links checked.
```

So what's going on!?

Comment: And I could not find where the `response` callback is documented at all... `dump(response)` currently gives an object like `{ "data": null }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code and it seems to be working fine for catching the 404 error in the on event. If you want to catch it within the thneOpen(), something like this would work:

```
casper.thenOpen('http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd', function() {
    if(this.status(false)['currentHTTPStatus'] === 404) {
        console.log('Error 404');
    } else {
        console.log('No Error 404');
    }
});
```

Or you could use the response directly, response['status'] will be 404 in this case.

```
casper.thenOpen('http://www.google.com/sadfafsdgfsd', function(response) {
    if(response['status'] === 404) {
        console.log('Error 404');
    } else {
        console.log('No Error 404');
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried and updated the result. Still can't catch 404 for some reason. `response` is `undefined`

Comment: That is strange, I can't see why it isn't working. I'll try to get some time to look at it today and get back to you.

Comment: Yah let me know. I am wondering if the Windows version has bug!?

Comment: It might be a Windows bug. I've run it on both versions of Casper and it works fine on my OSX machine. n1k0's 404check.js is returning ok because of it only checking for 404, 500, and you are undefined.                                                            if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 404) {
   this.warn(link + ' is missing (HTTP 404)');
} else if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 500) {
   this.warn(link + ' is broken (HTTP 500)');
} else {
   this.echo(link + f(' is okay (HTTP %s)', this.currentHTTPStatus));
}

Comment: sorry i can't be more help, I hope you manage to figure it out!

Comment: I just updated phantom 1.9.1 for Windows and it works. I guess there WAS a bug in 1.9 https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.1-windows.zip